# Unable to play songs or playlist in VLS using C# Vlc.DotNet.Core/Forms

Tags: c#, windows, vlc

I am trying to have my C# app start VLC, play songs, change volume etc.
I do not use a windows form. I intend to use code only and teh command will be later send via a voice recognition engine.
My code is:

```
 using Vlc.DotNet.Core;
    using Vlc.DotNet.Forms;
    .
    .
            vlcControl = new VlcControl();
            vlcControl.BeginInit();
            var vldDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC");
            vlcControl.VlcMediaplayerOptions = new[] { "-vv" };
            vlcControl.VlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC");
            vlcControl.EndInit();
            var song = new FileInfo(@"e:\Backup\Music\All\Youth Group - Forever young.mp3");
            vlcControl.Play(song);
```

I tried this and it did not play anything not was vlc invoked:

```
    var vlcPlayer = new VlcMediaPlayer(vldDir);
    vlcPlayer.SetMedia(song);
    vlcPlayer.Play();
```

I am certain that it is the correct path to VLS and to teh file. The file permission is also no issue.
What can I do to fix it and have it play the song?

There are no errors and no songs,
In the log i see:

> [0000024a70e5b160] main libvlc debug: VLC media player - 3.0.18
> Vetinari [0000024a70e5b160] main libvlc debug: Copyright ┬⌐ 1996-2022
> the VideoLAN team [0000024a70e5b160] main libvlc debug: revision
> 3.0.18-0-ge9eceaed4d [0000024a70e5b160] main libvlc debug: configured with /builds/videolan/vlc/extras/package/win32/../../../configure
> '--enable-update-check' '--enable-lua' '--enable-faad' '--enable-flac'
> '--enable-theora' '--enable-avcodec' '--enable-merge-ffmpeg'
> '--enable-dca' '--enable-mpc' '--enable-libass'
> '--enable-schroedinger' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-live555'
> '--enable-shout' '--enable-goom' '--enable-sse' '--enable-mmx'
> '--enable-libcddb' '--enable-zvbi' '--disable-telx' '--enable-nls'
> '--host=x86_64-w64-mingw32'
> '--with-contrib=../contrib/x86_64-w64-mingw32'
> '--with-breakpad=https://win.crashes.videolan.org' '--enable-qt'
> '--enable-skins2' '--enable-dvdread' '--enable-caca'
> 'host_alias=x86_64-w64-mingw32' 'CFLAGS= ' 'CXXFLAGS= '
> 'PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config'
> 'PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/pkgconfig'
> [0000024a70e5b160] main libvlc debug: using multimedia timers as clock
> source [0000024a70e5b160] main libvlc debug:  min period: 1 ms, max
> period: 1000000 ms [0000024a70e5b160] main libvlc debug: searching
> plug-in modules [0000024a70e5b160] main libvlc debug: loading plugins
> cache file C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins\plugins.dat
> [0000024a70e5b160] main libvlc debug: recursively browsing `C:\Program
> Files\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins' [0000024a70e5b160] main libvlc debug:
> plug-ins loaded: 496 modules [0000024a70e539b0] main logger debug:
> looking for logger module matching "any": 2 candidates
> [0000024a70e539b0] main logger debug: using logger module "console"
> [0000024a70e5b160] main libvlc debug: translation test: code is "C"
> [0000024a70ddf060] main keystore debug: looking for keystore module
> matching "memory": 3 candidates [0000024a70ddf060] main keystore
> debug: using keystore module "memory" [0000024a70e5b160] main libvlc
> debug: CPU has capabilities MMX MMXEXT SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1
> SSE4.2 FPU [0000024a727af980] main generic debug: creating audio
> output [0000024a72767f40] main audio output debug: looking for audio
> output module matching "any": 6 candidates [0000024a72767f40] mmdevice
> audio output debug: using default device [0000024a72767f40] mmdevice
> audio output debug: display name changed: VLC media player (LibVLC
> 3.0.18) [0000024a72767f40] mmdevice audio output debug: version 2 session control unavailable [0000024a72767f40] mmdevice audio output
> debug: volume from -64.000000 dB to +0.000000 dB with 0.031250 dB
> increments [0000024a72767f40] main audio output debug: using audio
> output module "mmdevice" [0000024a727af980] main generic debug:
> keeping audio output [0000024a7268e5f0] main input debug: Creating an
> input for 'Youth Group - Forever young.mp3' [0000024a7268e5f0] main
> input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB [0000024a7268e5f0]
> main input debug: using timeshift path:
> C:\Users\Chupi\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: do you have any error message ? what you mean with "unable to play songs" ...?

Comment: just updated the questions wit teh error codes, when there are errors

Comment: I doubt you can pass a windows file path directly to vlc like that

Comment: Have you tried var vv = new PathMedia(@"e:\Backup\Music\All\Youth Group - Forever young.mp3"); ?

Comment: PathMedia is not a method which my code is aware of. Where is it defined?

Comment: Did you check the log file: https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/issues/472?force_isolation=true.  Do you have a mp3 player installed.  Can you open the mp3 file manually with a player?

Comment: yes i can open the file with vlc as well but not via C#